# Is there a way to 'save' or recover a running Node.JS file?

Tags: node.js, digital-ocean, forever, file-recovery

I did something rather stupid and updated some `node.js` modules on a live server. Luckily the `process` is still running thanks to `Forever`, but the file `server.js` that made the whole thing tick no longer exists on the system.

Is there a way to get the file back in some manner since the `process` is still live?

I am running Ubuntu on DigitalOcean.

Comment: There is no way to magically extract the module files from the running process if that is what you're asking. Even if you were able to get an exact copy of the modules out, that may not account for *all* files (e.g. non-code files). IMHO you're SOL unless you have a backup somewhere.